# Search Value in VS2010 Debug Locals and/or expand all Nodes

Tags: visual-studio-2010, stack, locals

does someone might know **how to search for a value in the locals**
in visual studio 2010
or at least **how can I expand all nodes, subnodes**?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

if you record a macro on activating locals tools window on VS2010 it will generated this line of code,

```
DTE.Windows.Item(EnvDTE.Constants.vsWindowKindLocals).Activate()
```

after debugging this code and inspecting DTE.Windows'ActiveWindow when the active window is local I unfortunately couldn't find anything helpful, but give it a try and you may find sth helpful

if you just need parameters of a method you can use MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod() in System.Reflection namespace and it will serve you well by this private memeber

`((System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo)(currentMethod)).m_parameters`

that you can read programmatically by reflection or just quick watch it

Answer (score 0):

There are several items here that would let you do what you need, but you'll likely have to tweak the code first:

http://www.codeproject.com/info/search.aspx?artkw=quickwatch&sbo=kw